# Auto populate word document fields with database info

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I've been trying to set up a system where a user inputs data for a proposal, the data is saved to the database, then (when needed), the system will automatically place the data into tagged fields in a pre-made document. I have everything done as far as data entry is concerned, I just haven't been able to find any info on how to auto populate the tagged fields in the document itself.

Answer (score -1):

This might not be exactly what you are looking for but it sounds like you want to use MS Word fields.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/word-help/field-codes-in-word-HA010100426.aspx

Edit:
Sorry misread the question.  You one option is to do a mail merge.  In Word 2010 select the mailings tab then the start mail merge pull down and follow the wizard.  Super easy way to pull DB info into individual documents and you can easily select which records you want printed/created.